# How to obtain the gradient of a function as a function?

Tags: functions, syntax, vector, vector-calculus, built-in-symbols

The `Grad` function allows me to get the gradient of a function like this:

```
In:=
Grad[#1 + #2^2 &[x, y], {x, y}]
Out:=
{1, 2 y}
```

The gradient is expressed in terms of the symbols x and y that I provided. However I would like to get the gradient in this form, as a function:

```
{1, 2 #2}&
```

Operations such as this that act on functions, rather than variables, are known in mathematics as operators. Gradient is an operator.

Answer (score 7):

How about this?:

```
Evaluate@Grad[#1 + #2^2, {#1, #2}] &
(*  {1, 2 #2} &  *)
```

---

Or for pure obfuscatory fun:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

I'd like to reinstate to my first answer (see edit history),

```
Evaluate@Grad[#1 + #2^2 &[#1, #2], {#1, #2}] &
```

even though `#1 + #2^2 &[#1, #2]`, which equals `#1 + #2^2` and seemed redundant, because it has the right general form,

```
Evaluate@Grad[f[#1, #2], {#1, #2}] &
```

or equivalently in nonletterese,

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This doesn't work if the function isn't expressed as a pure function but for example like this: myF[x_, y_] := x + y^2

Comment: @MichaelE2 tis the season for obfuscatory fun :)

Comment: @user Not sure what "this" meant in your case, but  `Evaluate@Grad[myF[#1, #2], {#1, #2}] &` works for me.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I meant that `Evaluate@Grad[myF, {#1, #2}] &` doesn't work...

Comment: @user No, it wouldn't, but that's not equivalent, is it?  I mean for `Grad` you can't supply a pure function or function head, but have to also supply its inputs. -- Even with `Derivative` you have to supply inputs to get what you want: `Evaluate@{Derivative[1, 0][myF][#1, #2], Derivative[0, 1][myF][#1, #2]} &`

Comment: @user Here's a long-winded version that makes it clearer how to plug in another function: `Evaluate@Grad[#1 + #2^2 &[#1, #2], {#1, #2}] &` -- I had this originally but went for the shorter form.

Comment: For me `myF[x_, y_] := x + y^2; Derivative[0, 1][myF]` works just fine. What do you mean with "Even with Derivative you have to supply inputs to get what you want"?

Comment: @user Oh, I seem to have misread the output you desired.  My solution does it the way I would want it.  You seem to have something else in mind.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Actually I miswrote my desired output. Your output is correct. Sorry about that...  :)

Comment: @user Then doesn't `Derivative[0, 1][myF]` put the `&` in the wrong place (for the full gradient)?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes it does....

Answer (score 7):

Being an anti-obfuscatorian by nature, I recommend

```
f[x_, y_] = Grad[Function[{x, y}, x + y^2][x, y], {x, y}];
```

or

```
g[x_, y_] = Grad[#1 + #2^2 &[x, y], {x, y}];
```

Then

```
Through[{f, g}[u, v]]
```

> `{{1, 2 v}, {1, 2 v}}`

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps:

```
grd[f_, v_][n_] := Grad[f @@ v, v] /. Thread[v -> n]
```

Testing various functions:-

```
q = #1^2 - #2^3 &;
r[x_, y_] := x^2 Sin[y];
s = Function[{u, v}, u^2 + 3 v^4];
test1 = grd[q, {x, y}];
test2 = grd[r, {x, y}];
test3 = grd[s, {x, y}];
test1[{a, b}]
test2[{a, b}]
test3[{a, b}]
```

[image]

and if you want it to behave f[x,y]$\mapsto$ g[x,y] rather than g[{x,y}]:

```
grad[f_, v_][n__] := grd[f, v][{n}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I created two functions to do this job.
1.

```
In:=
        MapIndexed[
   Function[
     {x, y},
     (
        Derivative @@ Normal[
          SparseArray[#2[[1]] -> #1, Length@y]
          ]
        )[x] &
     ][#1, #2],
   #2] &[
 #1 + #2^2 &,
 {1, 1}
 ]
Out:=
{1 &, 2 #2 &}
```

The first argument is the function and the second argument is a list of the degrees of derivatives to be taken with respect to corresponding slot.


2.

```
In:=
Function[#2, Evaluate[Grad[#1 @@ #2, #2]]] &[#1 + #2^2 &, {x, y}]
Out:=
Function[{x, y}, {1, 2 y}]
```

In this approach the function is given a list of arbitrary symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to create a gradient function from a regular function:

```
MakeGrad[func_] :=
    With[
    {
        args = {##},
        tempNames = Unique[]& /@ Range[Length[{##}]]
    },
    Grad[(func @@ tempNames), tempNames] /. Thread[tempNames -> args]] &
```

You can then do something like:

```
  f[x_, y_, z_] := x^2 y + z
  f' := MakeGrad[f]
```

And use it like a function:

```
  f'[a, b, c]
  {2 a b, a^2, 1}
```