# Gradient of interpolated 3D data in mathematica 9

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, interpolation

```
tt = Flatten[Table[{x, y, z, btot[x, y, z]}, {x, -1, 1, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1,0.1}, {z, -1, 1, 0.1}], 2];
ff = Interpolation[tt]
```

Till here it is working fine as it is returning the values of the interpolated function at various `{x,y,z}` points.

Then I want to find the gradient of this interpolated function. But when I am using

```
ffd[x_,y_,z_]:= D[ff[x,y,z],{{x,y,z}}]
```

I am not getting the gradient.

Comment: closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102812/5478

Comment: All you have to do is replace the `:=` in your code with `=` and it should work

Comment: It didnt even work by replacing `:=` with `=`.

Comment: @SamridhiGambhir "didn't work" or "not getting the gradient" are vague statements which won't help you getting the answer fast.

Comment: @SamridhiGambhir Try `Remove[ffd]` before trying with `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
ffd[x_,y_,z_]:= D[ff[x,y,z],{{x,y,z}}]
```

the values of x, y, and z are substituted as arguments causing differentation wrt. numbers, i.e. nonsense. Moreover, you are using SetDelayed, which differentiate once for every call, which rather should be once for all time.

The solution to both problem is replacing SetDelayed with Set:

```
ffd[x_,y_,z_]= D[ff[x,y,z],{{x,y,z}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define your function like this, then  e.g. `ffd[.5, .5, .5]` is really `D[ff[.5, .5, .5], {{.5, .5, .5}}]`.

to avoid scoping issues with

```
x=5;
ffd[x_, y_, z_] = D[ff[x, y, z], {{x, y, z}}]
```

you can use

```
ffd = Evaluate[D[ff[#, #2, #3], {{#, #2, #3}}]] &
```

`&` means there is a held `Function` so we have to use `Evaluate` to force computation of gradien so it is not repeated each time.